# Why cost of integrated circuits (IC) are higher when purchase online than to local market

Tags: integrated-circuit

Why cost of integrated circuits are higher when purchase online than to local market.
For example SN7404N on Digi-Key costs around $2 but same i got from local market in $0.2

Comment: there is no mention of your location in your profile, where are these local markets located?

Comment: This looks like old or salvaged parts.... I would not be surprised to find a few faulty one... It can make soldering a challenge.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: [It was discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9074074#9074074)

Answer (score 4):

If your local market is like a flea market you the price can be anything, and so can the quality. Any correlation between the two is just a coincidence.

That particular chip you mention is a dinosaur: a plain (pre-schottky) TTL chip. The amazing thing is that you can still buy them at all. A marginally more recent 74LS04 goes at 0.25 (or 0.75 if you insist on DIP).

The chip one would choose now (when you would need it at all) would be a 74HC04 or 74HCT04. For some reason they are not particularly cheaper at Digikey, but at Mouser a 7$HC04 goes at ~ E 0.14 (@1, down to ~ 0.06 @1k).

To summarize:

- you took a bad example
- always look wider than just one supplier (use www.findchips.com !)
- if you are OK with flea market quality...
  -

Comment: I suspect OP is in India. Almost any legacy DIP part for a fast-moving IC is dirt cheap here because those are the ones that sell most: Hand-soldering with board test can be contracted for 4 to 8 cents per 100 junctions. Conversely, any SMD IC is at prices often 3 to 10 times as much as on OctoPart searches, if available at all. The DIP parts aren't flea market items, the major manufacturers officially sell DIPs at way below any price the western market sees. Also, I suspect Digikey charges a massive inventory mark-up on DIPs, as DIPs take more storage and sell more slowly for them.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh that's truly interesting information!